# MPI: mpiexec third parameter not clear

Tags: mpi, mpich

What exactly is the third parameter in the following MPI command

```
mpiexec -n 2 cpi
```

Is it no. of cores? So if I am running on Pentium 4 , shall I make it 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `-n 2`: spawn two processes.
- `cpi`: the executable.

Experiment with what is faster, one or two or more processes. Some codes run best with one process per core, some codes benefit from oversubscription.

Comment: On a single core machine, if I give -n 2, it means two processes will work in time sharing mode. Am I right?

Comment: Ok. I have another issue to [launch the jobs on multiple PCs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332339/mpi-running-the-code-across-multiple-pcs-in-lan). I hope you can help me out

Comment: @gpuguy that's a question about how to install MPICH2 on a cluster. I've never done that, I don't know what's involved.